# Cannot reindex due to duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to change the frequency of my dataframe using:

```
df2 = df.resample('M').asfreq()
```

or

```
df = df.asfreq('M')
```

It’s indexed on “datetime” but I get the following error message:

```
"ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"
```

After a reading other posts this is due to duplicate entries in my index but I only have duplicates in terms of date not time i.e. when I check using:

```
df[df.index.duplicated()]
```

I get:

- 2015-08-11 02:36:42
- 2015-08-11 06:07:17
- 2015-08-12 01:52:13
- 2015-08-12 04:55:13

They’re not actually duplicated if you look at the timestamp as a whole. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there are duplicates, only need test them by `keep=False` for see all duplicated index values:

```
df[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Possible solution is aggregate, e.g. by `sum` or `mean` - then get unique DatetimeIndex with month frequency:

```
df2 = df.resample('M').sum()
```